# Where is "The Zen of Python" located in the CPython source code?

Tags: python

You of course know what happens when you `import this`, but **where is the Zen located in the interpreter source code**?

I'd searched the string *"Readability counts"* in a local clone but haven't found anything relevant.

Searching `"zen of python" site:hg.python.org` in Google gives me no result at all.

Comment: `this.py` is encrypted (ROT-13), which is why you're not finding the text.

Comment: If you `import this`, then `import inspect`, you can just `print(inspect.getsource(this))` to see the source, or `print(inspect.getsourcefile(this))` to find the filename (or, usually, just `this.__file__`).

Comment: Notably, the Zen of Python doesn't use *any* special source magic to handle "import this" - it just imports/executes the module normally.

Comment: Also see [import this and The Zen of Python](http://www.wefearchange.org/2010/06/import-this-and-zen-of-python.html) from Barry Warsaw's blog.

Comment: For future reference, `print inspect.getsource(this)` is very handy.

Comment: > where is the Zen located in the interpreter source code?

this made my day.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a file called [`this.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/c3896275c0f6/Lib/this.py) in the Lib directory.

The string is encoded using [ROT-13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT-13) so it's not searchable. The code to decode it is in the file.

Answer (score 5):

It ROT-13's it:

```
>>> import this # imports the file "this.py"
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
# ... etc ...
>>> this.s # encoded text
"Gur Mra bs Clguba, ol Gvz Crgref\n\nOrnhgvshy vf orggre guna htyl.\nRkcyvpvg vf orggre guna vzcyvpvg.\nFvzcyr vf orggre guna pbzcyrk.\nPbzcyrk vf orggre guna pbzcyvpngrq.\nSyng vf orggre guna arfgrq.\nFcnefr vf orggre guna qrafr.\nErnqnovyvgl pbhagf.\nFcrpvny pnfrf nera'g fcrpvny rabhtu gb oernx gur ehyrf.\nNygubhtu cenpgvpnyvgl orngf chevgl.\nReebef fubhyq arire cnff fvyragyl.\nHayrff rkcyvpvgyl fvyraprq.\nVa gur snpr bs nzovthvgl, ershfr gur grzcgngvba gb thrff.\nGurer fubhyq or bar-- naq cersrenoyl bayl bar --boivbhf jnl gb qb vg.\nNygubhtu gung jnl znl abg or boivbhf ng svefg hayrff lbh'er Qhgpu.\nAbj vf orggre guna arire.\nNygubhtu arire vf bsgra orggre guna *evtug* abj.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf uneq gb rkcynva, vg'f n onq vqrn.\nVs gur vzcyrzragngvba vf rnfl gb rkcynva, vg znl or n tbbq vqrn.\nAnzrfcnprf ner bar ubaxvat terng vqrn -- yrg'f qb zber bs gubfr!"
>>> this.d # dictionary
{'A': 'N', 'C': 'P', 'B': 'O', 'E': 'R', 'D': 'Q', 'G': 'T', 'F': 'S', 'I': 'V', 'H': 'U', 'K': 'X', 'J': 'W', 'M': 'Z', 'L': 'Y', 'O': 'B', 'N': 'A', 'Q': 'D', 'P': 'C', 'S': 'F', 'R': 'E', 'U': 'H', 'T': 'G', 'W': 'J', 'V': 'I', 'Y': 'L', 'X': 'K', 'Z': 'M', 'a': 'n', 'c': 'p', 'b': 'o', 'e': 'r', 'd': 'q', 'g': 't', 'f': 's', 'i': 'v', 'h': 'u', 'k': 'x', 'j': 'w', 'm': 'z', 'l': 'y', 'o': 'b', 'n': 'a', 'q': 'd', 'p': 'c', 's': 'f', 'r': 'e', 'u': 'h', 't': 'g', 'w': 'j', 'v': 'i', 'y': 'l', 'x': 'k', 'z': 'm'}
```

The actual code that decodes it is this:

```
d = {}
for c in (65, 97):
    for i in range(26):
        d[chr(i+c)] = chr((i+13) % 26 + c)

print "".join([d.get(c, c) for c in s])
```